# Assign enum as property c#

Tags: c#, enums, properties, custom-attributes

I did not find any answer on the forum (however if there is one please let me know). I am writing backend structure for the ASP.NET MVC app and have some troubles with C# case.

I am wondering if such a solution is possible to happen (and need to do a following thing the way I described or similarly).
I will show the problem in the example below, because I do not know how to say it clearly in words.

I have defined Enum as following:

```
public enum myEnum
{
    FirstOpt = 0,
    SecondOpt= 1,
    ThirdOpt = 2,

    Unknown = -1,
}
```

Now, I want to assign myEnum in the different part of my solution in the custom attribute.

The attribute looks the following way:

```
    public class SearchTypeAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public Type SType { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<object> SItems { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I want to use it in the following way:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [SearchTypeAttribute(
        SType = typeof(Enums.myEnum),
        SItems =  Enum.GetValues(typeof(Enums.myEnum))
    )]
    public string Type{ get; set; } // later to this item will be assigned string name of the assigned value
 }
```

When I am doing this, the following error appears:

*Error  CS0655  'SItems' is not a valid named attribute argument because it is not a valid attribute parameter type*

I was also trying to assign it as here:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [SearchTypeAttribute(
        SType = typeof(Enums.myEnum),
        SItems =  Enums.myEnum // here !
    )]
    public string Type{ get; set; } 

 }
```

But I still have no idea what "Type" of property I should use in my SearchTypeAttribute, to be able to assign those values there.

I am doing this to be able to generate different types of fields in search bars in the views later.
Then in my code I want to assign the list of enum values or the specific enum to some variable, so I can then, operate on those values.

What types should I use to assign this type of data *SItems* ?
Is there other approach to do it ? 
I am not yet really advanced in c#. Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: An attribute is a **compile-time** thing. So you have to provide all the information at compile-time also. However `Enum.GetValues` will be executed at **runtime**, making it impossible to be used for an attribute. The only way to achieve this is by writing the possible enum-values directy into the attribute.

Comment: This is a fairly unusual desig, what is the use case here? My Spidey senses tells me this has XY written all over it

Comment: If you remove the `SItems` property from the attribute you can use your attribute to generate the items for the UI **at runtime** using `Enum.GetValues()`. You only need `SType` which is in the attribute to do that.

Comment: @TheGeneral I need to generate those enums as dropdownlists in views. Each view has different fields and some must be dropdowns based on enums. I am using ViewData[] and DropdownList to do it and so far it worked perfectly for one enum. But when I have 10 dropdownlists to generate in the view I don't want to cope-paste the same code and change names of ViewData (ViewData["enumOne"], ViewData["enumTwo"] etc). Instead I want to generate them in the loop. And that is why I need to "pair" those enums with the properties. Do you know maybe is there any way to achieve my goal in any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An attribute is a **compile-time** thing. So you have to provide all the information at **compile-time** also. However `Enum.GetValues` will be executed at **runtime**, making it impossible to be used for an attribute. The only way to achieve this is by writing the possible enum-values directy into the attribute:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [SearchTypeAttribute(
        SType = typeof(Enums.myEnum),
        SItems =  new[] { Enums.FirstOpt, Enums.SecondOpt, ...}
    )]
    public string Type{ get; set; } 

 }
```

Apart from this I can´t see why your `SItems` is of type `IEnumerable<object>`, when it obviously has only `Enums`-elements in it. It´s not even possible to use an `IEnumerable` on an attribute, only arrays of primitive types are allowed, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/attributes.md#attribute-parameter-types). So `SItems` should be an `Enums[]`.

Another approach is to rely on the attributes constructor and initialize `SItems` from there:

```
public class SearchTypeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public SearchTypeAttribute(Type type)
    {
        this.SType = type;
        this.SItems = Enum.GetValues(type);
    }

}
```

Now simply use the attribute as follows:

```
[SearchTypeAttribute(typeof(Enums.myEnum))]
public string Type{ get; set; }
```